# Connecting a high range (atleast 10m) RFID reader with Pi

Tags: server, rfid

Is it possible to connect an RFID reader like the Motorola UHF Reader (Motorola FX7400) with Raspberry Pi..?

I just want to know whether these high end systems are compatible with Pi. Mostly NFC (Near Field Communication) based readers are used for developing a prototype, but when it comes to an automated toll gate system where we make use of a PC, can Pi be a replacement provided that a central main server will do the validation and other stuffs and Pi for connecting to RFID reader.??

Comment: The FX7400 documentation says it's an ethernet device, so it won't matter what you have watching for data.  If you are building a toll gate to collect revenue it would make sense to have a fault tolerant server grade system collecting the data.  If on the other hand it's a cattle gate where the mission is less critical a pi might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can connect them. I don't see why you would like to, though - the FX7400 has ethernet, and if you have a server grade machine somewhere in the network, it's probably better to let that machine do the job. Otherwise a pi could probably do it, but pis are not manufactured to be part of critical infrastructure.